# Transform of a function of three random variables

Tags: probability, integral-transforms

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be independent random variables, where X is Bernoulli with parameter $1/3$, $Y$
is exponential with parameter $2$, and $Z$ is Poisson with parameter $3$.

(a) Consider the new random variable $U = XY + (1 - X)Z$ . Find the transform
associated with $U$.

(b) Find the transform associated with $2Z + 3$.

(c) Find the transform associated with $Y + Z$.

I know that I can get the transform of a sum of random variables by multiplying their transforms but I don't understand how I can get the complete transform of $U$.

Comment: Hint: Note that $U = Y$ w.p. $1/3$ and $U = Z$ w.p. $2/3$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}[e^{sU}] = \frac{1}{3} \mathbb{E}[e^{sY}] + \frac{2}{3} \mathbb{E}[e^{sZ}]$.

Comment: More generally, the key is to write that $\mathbb{E}[e^{sU}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{sU} \mid Y,Z]]$ and see where that leads you.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how I can get the complete transform of U.

If $X=0$, the rv U is discrete and it is a poisson $Po(3)$. This happens with probabilty $\frac{2}{3}$

If $X=1$, the rv U is continuous and it is a $Exp(2)$. This happens with probabilty $\frac{1}{3}$

Thus

$$f_U(u)=\frac{2}{3}e^{-2u}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(u)+\frac{2}{3}\frac{e^{-3}3^u}{u!}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{0;1;2;3;...\}}(u)$$

---

Show your attempts for the rest of the questions (if you want that someone helps you)